# How to add user_id to login parameter in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

Below is some method in a trait `AuthenticatesUsers` where `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth`, Laravel.

```
   ...
    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

   ...

    public function username()
    {
        return 'email';
    }
```

Originally, my goal is to make another login form with user_id and password in mobile device, so this will check Auth() and if success, it will work some method and automatically logout after then. could you tell me detailed advice?

**Additional question.**

as `Jaskaran Singh's` advice I added it also as below.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if($request->Inn == 'Inn') {
        return redirect()->route('mobiles_start', ['Inn' => 'Inn']);
    }

    elseif($request->Ut == 'Ut') {
        return redirect()->route('mobiles_destroy', ['Ut' => 'Ut']);
    }

    return view('welcome');
}
```

but if login failed, then it is redirected back to the `/login` page instead of expected view page that pre defined in the route(mobiles_start and mobiles_destroy) above.
How could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php add the following functions, this will override the default functions in AuthenticatesUsers trait.

add username() function

```
public function username()
{
    if(request('id')){
        return 'id'; // if request contains id then return it
    }
    return 'email'; // else return email
}
```

add validateLogin() function

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required', //remove |string
        'password' => 'required|string',
    ]);
}
```

that's it.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the expected result without touching the core file. :)

Comment: Could you give me some more advice to additional question? :)

Comment: Sure buddy :)
Go ahead!

Answer (score 2):

You can login with User ID like this:

```
if(Auth::loginUsingId($user->id)){
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);
}
```

You don't have to extend the core trait or any core Laravel code.

Comment: thanks, originally, my goal is to make another login form with user_id and password in mobile device, so this will check Auth() and if success, it will work some method and automatically logout after then. could you tell me detailed advice?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. This method will simply let you log in with just the user id. So you can fetch the user first and pass the id to the `loginUsingId()` method and it should work no matter where you come from.

Comment: where posited `loginUsingId()`? could you tell me path it? :)

Comment: Just use that wherever you log the user in. Probably in your controller.